# show all checked values and remove TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table>
    <tr><td>aaa</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="yes[]" value="aaa" checked /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>bbb</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="yes[]" value="bbb" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ccc</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="yes[]" value="ccc" checked /></td></tr>
</table>


<span id="delete">delete</span>

var val = $(input[checkbox]).val();
alert(val);

$('#delete').click(function(){
    //here should be delete all TR if input is not checked. how?
})
```

how can i show all checked values and how can i delete all TR if input in this TR is not checked?

LIVE EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/RYrA4/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the appropriate elements, then select the parent `tr`s and finally remove them: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/RYrA4/3/.

```
$('#delete').click(function(){
    $(":checkbox[name='yes[]']:not(:checked)") // select non-checked checkboxes
        .parent()  // <td>s (parents of checkboxes)
        .parent()  // <tr>s (parents of <td>s)
        .remove(); // remove <tr>s
})
```

Comment: @Paul Attuck: You can use `.map` to map elements to their values: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/RYrA4/6/.

Answer (score 3):

The super simple way:

```
$('#delete').click(function(){
    $(":checkbox[name='yes[]']:not(:checked)").parents('tr').remove();
})
```

You could do an "each" loop, if you want to achieve more, change something :)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method finds the nearest tag defined by the selector starting at the current element and progressing up the tree:

```
$('#delete').click(function(){
    $("input:checkbox[name='yes[]']:not(:checked)").closest('tr').remove();
})
```

Comment: The space causes it to be a descendant selector.

Comment: @pimvdb - yep, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Do you wish to show alerts for each checked checkbox or one alert will suffice? For individual alerts:

```
$("#delete").click(function()
{
    var allCheckBoxes = $("input:checkbox[name='yes[]']"),
    selectedCheckBoxes = allCheckBoxes.filter(":checked"),
    unselectedCheckboxes = allCheckBoxes.not(":checked");
    unselectedCheckboxes.closest("tr").remove();
    selectedCheckBoxes.each(function()
                           {
                              alert(this.value);
                           });

}
```

For a single alert we can create a comma separated string in the "each" function and then alert it.